# Force focus event inside of a slot element

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I'm trying to focus an element that's inside of a slot element that it's being used in a custom-element.

Inside of my custom element I query for the slot element, than I use the method .assignedElements, which is just one div, and then I query inside of that element to find the input that I want. After that i use the method .focus() to well, focus the input.. But that doesn't work.

Please let me know if anyone can help

I'm currently doing all that with Stencil component.

Stencil web component.

```
<tab-component> This is a web-component with a render method that returns <slot>
now I use tab-component inside of another web-component inside of it's render method, using a native yes, input.
```

I can't honestly say more than that, if anyone has any experience trying to access an input inside of a web component slot, please let know.

Comment: you should provide some minimal code

Comment: Is the "input", you're referring to, a native `<input>` element? Otherwise it might not support/implement the `focus()` method.